# No Directionality widget found ; I want to use only Container and Text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, widget, flutter-widget, statefulwidget

I just run the basic flutter code.
I want to make stateful widget, only containing Text("hi")
so I write my code like below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Text("hi");
  }
}
```

but I got error
No Directionality widget found.
RichText widgets require a Directionality widget ancestor

I can fix my error to add textDirection attribute,
but I wonder when I use Text I didn't get that error even if I don't use that attribute.
I just want to use only Text, Container

Comment: Wrap your text widget with a container and wrap that container in scaffold / Material App. Every flutter code must be wrapped in scaffold or material app.

Surely it will give you desire output also learn Material app widget more in deep it will help you in future

Answer (score 1):

i think its because you dont have MaterialApp

try it like this will work

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp1());
}
class MyApp1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
     home: MyApp(),
    );
  }
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Text("hi"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Text` needs a `Directionality` widget to provide information on whether the text is "left-to-right" or "right-to-left". Usually this is done (behind the scene) by `MaterialApp` widget. If you don't want to use that, you could provide one yourself, and specify the text direction.

Minimal code for a hello world:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Text("Hello world."),
    ),
  );
}
```